# Troubleshooting System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have a custom Windows Service that is installed on about 500 production systems that harvests information about the machine (Hard drive size / freespace, is a RAID controller installed, etc.)  Last week I noticed that one of the servers wasn't reporting in, so I logged  into the machine and I noticed that the service was indeed throwing exceptions.

Here is the problem: The exceptions are all of type System.AccessViolationException but I am not sure why I am seeing them all of a sudden.  They happen in two different places: once is where I make a call to the SqlServerCe assemblies (unmanaged) and the other place is where I attempt to free a buffer in NetApi32.dll (that code is below)

```
    private static string GetNetworkName()
    {
        int result = 0;
        string network = null;
        IntPtr pDomain = IntPtr.Zero;
        NetJoinStatus status = NetJoinStatus.NetSetupUnknownStatus;
        try
        {
            result = NetGetJoinInformation(null, out pDomain, out status);
            if (result == ErrorSuccess && status == NetJoinStatus.NetSetupDomainName)
            {
                network = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pDomain);
            }
            else if (result == ErrorSuccess && status == NetJoinStatus.NetSetupWorkgroupName)
            {
                network = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pDomain);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (pDomain != IntPtr.Zero) NetApiBufferFree(pDomain);
        }
        if (network == null) network = "";
        return network;
    }
```

The exception is thrown inside the finally block. I am at a loss on how to fix this problem; I am not seeing the issue on any other servers, there have been no updates to the service itself in several years, etc.  The last thing to happen on the machine prior to the service failing was that a Windows update related to Crypt32 and ASP.NET was downloaded and installed, but I don't feel that that is relevant to the problem at hand.

Are there any steps that I can take to figure out why this problem is occurring? I understand that AccessViolationException typically means that unmanaged code has tried to address an invalid address in memory, but is there anyway for me to isolate why that is happening and correct it?

Comment: The error checking is a bit wonky. Only call NetApiBufferFree if NetGetJoinInformation succeeds. I doubt that's the problem. Hence this just being a comment.

Comment: The code in general is wonky.  Ya for inherited projects!  Nevertheless, I will see if moving NetApiBufferFree around accomplishes anything.  Thanks!